# Can I store a part of code inside a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to make a complex MongoDB query using mongoose.

Let's assume I have a Post model that has a field **isGlobal** : Boolean and others like **hashtags**, **groups**

The task is to show posts that have needed **hashtags** or **groups** but also can be **isGlobal** true or false (a usere can select his options, for example to show only posts from groups or his hashtags etc).

But anyway, I'm trying to do something like this.

1. Saving a part of a code in a variable

```
var showPublicContent = public === true
        ? {
            isGlobal: true,
          }
        : {};
```

2. As you may guess using it like this

```
Post.find({
          $and: [
            {
              $or: [
                {
                  groups: {
                    $in: userGroups,
                  },
                },
                {
                  showPublicContent
                }
               ]
             },
            ..... other stuff
           ],
           .... other stuff
  })
```

So, question is - can I do something like what I showed up here or it's messy and better to do separate queries.

Comment: `{ ...showPublicContent }`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70768956/3027266

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the issue in my code, there is an extra pair parenthesis.

So, just leave this code as it is.

```
var showPublicContent = public === true
        ? {
            isGlobal: true,
          }
        : {};
```

And here, inside the $or array delete {} that surrounds the **showPublicContent**

```
Post.find({
          $and: [
            {
              $or: [
                {
                  groups: {
                    $in: userGroups,
                  },
                },
                showPublicContent,
               ]
             },
            ..... other stuff
           ],
           .... other stuff
  })
```

Now, it works. It seems I have to refactor a lot of code

**UPDATE:**
The solution above works, **BUT** putting {} into the find query returns ALL data from the database, so finally I did just an array of queries like

```
let orQueryArray = [];

if (public) {
    orQueryArray.push({
        isGlobal: true
   });
}
```

and then just put it in

```
    Post.find({
        $or : orQueryArray
    })
```